# a question on Lindelöf spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{(x,y)\in {\Bbb R}^2:y>0\}$ is the subspace of ${\Bbb R}^2$ with the usual topology, then it is still Lindelöf?

If not, with which topology can $X$ be made to be Lindelöf?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R^2$ where you’ve written $R$?

Comment: I assumed that was the case; I hope I was correct!

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $X$ is Lindelöf: this is immediate from the fact that it is second countable. Every second countable space is hereditarily second countable and therefore hereditarily Lindelöf.

**Added:** As Mariano points out in the comments, you can also use the fact that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, which is itself Lindelöf.

Comment: The space is even homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ so, assuming the «still» in the question means that the OP knows $\mathbb R^2$ is Lindelöf, then he also knows $X$ is Lindelöf :)

Comment: @Mariano: Good point; I’ll add it to the answer.